# symfony collectiontype data-prototype output incomplete, only empty div rendered

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have a UserType form that's used to edit User entities. Each User has a collection of Permission's which is managed through a CollectionType with

```
[ 'entry_type'=>'PermissionType', 'allow_add'=>true, 'prototype'=>true ]
```

When a User object is loaded from Doctrine, the permissions are correct and they are displayed correctly when the view is rendered. When i render the permissions seperately as so:

```
                {%for R in form.permissions%}
                {{form_widget(R)}}{{form_label(R)}}{{form_errors(R)}}
                {%endfor%}
```

The data-attribute tag of my containing element is rendered as so:

```
data-prototype="{{form_widget(form.permissions.vars.prototype)|e}}"
```

But then the prototype only contains an empty div (but correctly named id).

```
data-prototype="&lt;div id=&quot;user_permissions___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

The documentation states this:

```
If you render your whole "tags" sub-form at once (e.g. 
form_row(form.tags)), then the prototype is automatically available on 
the outer div as the data-prototype attribute, similar to what you see 
above.
```

So i tried this approach too, and then the data-prototype attribute of the generated div contains a label as well:

```
data-prototype="&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot;required&quot;&gt;__name__label__&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;user_permissions___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

The three PermissionTypes which are generated for my test case generate perfect output otherwise.

So my question is: what could be the cause for my prototype not being rendered correctly? Did i uncover a bug perhaps? I also tried the case of rendering the complete form at once, same as the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I made a mistake. I was adding certain input elements to the form in a PRE_SET_DATA FormEvent, because I wanted to change the label to reflect some of the data. But, when Symfony generates the data-prototype, it calls buildForm but it doesn't set any data. So the resulting empty div was actually quite correct. Building the form directly in buildForm resolved it.